# Regarding travelers who have over stayed their visa expiration--

Tags: dual-nationality, overstaying, south-africa

I recently visited Cape Town, SA. and during my stay I pushed my departure date back and eventually overstayed my visa allowance. I have been declared undesirable in South Africa on my American passport for 5 years.

My question is, I am also a German citizen and I have a German passport. Would border patrol overlook my entering the country with this passport, and would a notice of my declared undesirability be seen?

Is it possible for border patrol to cross-reference my dual citizenship passports?